# Storing results of script execution to a file

Tags: php

I have built an estimating application where I type in some fields hit submit and the data is saved to my database and creates an on the fly estimate with everything that I typed in.  Now they issue I am having is I want to save the output page as a file to my webserver for later viewing, but I can only find examples that save all of my code including the `ECHO $Field1`.   How can I save the outputted results to a file.  The same results one would see if they right clicked on the outputted page and choose view source.   I was hoping to do it only using PHP.

I tried this already.....

```
<?php
ob_start();
// all your logic and code for displaying
$output = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents($uniquehtml,$output);
// save output page to the html file
?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not saving that data into a variable, then storing it and then outputting it?

Comment: That looks like it should work fine. What do you get in the file?

Comment: please format your code so that it spans multiple lines (otherwise it is hard to read). Also, try to write as clear as possible, and re-read things to see if they make sense. In your code, there is no "ECHO $Field".

Comment: Thanks for the reply's I am looking for something that where it says //process form // your code goes here to put the source code of the current page. The HTML results. I don't want to save a file that has the PHP in it. I hope I am explaining this correctly

Answer (score 1):

use something like this in your output page

```
//buffer output
ob_start();

//process form
//your code goes here

//save & flush buffer in a file
$buffer = ob_get_flush();
file_put_contents('buffer.txt', $buffer, FILE_APPEND);
```

The FILE_APPEND keeps adding output to the same file. Otherwise, create a new file name each time it writes. You could append time() to the file name, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's I am looking for something that where it says //process form // your code goes here to put the source code of the current page.  The HTML results.  I don't want to save a file that has the PHP in it.  I hope I am explaining this correctly

Comment: You're welcome. That's what my example is supposed to do. Are you saying it's saving the PHP file itself? That shouldn't happen, at least if your source file has .php extension.

Comment: what is happening is when I go to use the code above my file has html and php in the code mixed ex:[code]<td width="37%" height="43"> <p align="left"><font size="2"><b>DATE: </b> <?php echo $dated ?> <br> </font><font size="2"><b>ESTIMATE #:</b> <?php echo $estimatenumber ?> </font></p> </td> [/code] I am getting an error

Comment: you can edit your question some more to add the code that's causing a problem. The part you put in looks ok to me, although <font> is deprecated, and <br /> is better than <br>

Comment: I would also put a semi-colon after each echo statement, like <?php echo $dated;?> although I don't think that's required